# Не получаеться отправить сообщение пользователю от бота ВК

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Не получаеться через бота отправить сообщение, хотя на другом компьютере всё ок, может дело в PyCharm?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
python
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType


def write_msg(user_id, message):
    vk.method('message.send', {'user_id':user_id, 'message':message,
                               'random_id':0})

token = "abc...."

vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)

longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk)
write_msg(194674349, '123')
```

Comment: Есть ошибки? Почему вы думаете что проблема в IDE?

Comment: Ну вроде в тексте ошибки всё предельно ясно написано. Какое именно слово вам непонятно?

Comment: @andreymal что именно нужно сделать для исправления ошибки? На другом ПК с тем же кодом всё работало

Comment: И с тем же самым токеном?

Comment: И user_id тоже тот же самый?

Comment: @andreymal токен поменял, а юзер айди тот же

Comment: Ну вот и очевидно, что токен у вас неправильный, не имеющий нужных прав доступа

Comment: @andreymal токен я создавал со всеми разрешениями

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в 6-ой строке в части "message.send" необходимо было дописать букву S в конце слова message. "messages.send"